# WSO2 ESB: transform XML to JSON and send to endpoint

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am unable to transform an incoming SOAP Payload into JSON and send that to an Endpoint.

Did somebody ever did that?
If so, could you please share how you did?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use XSLT transformation to achieve the task. Here is a [sample](http://synapse.apache.org/userguide/samples/sample158.html) which will guide you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the payloadFactory Mediator.
https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/PayloadFactory+Mediator

You have to add the below line to convert the XML payload to JSON

```
 <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2" />
```

Some sample below.

```
<payloadFactory media-type="json">
        <format>
            {
            "userIdentifier": {
                "id": "$1"              
            }
            }
        </format>
        <args>
            <arg expression="get-property('uri.var.id')"></arg>
        </args>
    </payloadFactory>

<property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2" />
```